# Pub/Sub csv data to Dataflow to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

My pipeline is IoTCore -> Pub/Sub -> Dataflow -> BigQuery. Initially the data I was getting was Json format and the pipeline was working properly. Now I need to shift to csv and the issue is the Google defined dataflow template I was using uses Json input instead of csv. Is there an easy way of transfering csv data from pub/sub to bigquery through dataflow. The template can probably be changed but it is implemented in Java which I have never used so would take a long time to implement. I also considered implementing an entire custom template in python but that would take too long.
Here is a link to the template provided by google:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java

Sample: Currently my pub/sub messages are JSON and these work correctly

```
"{"Id":"123","Temperature":"50","Charge":"90"}"
```

But I need to change this to comma seperated values

```
"123,50,90"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy: Do nothing!! If you have a look to [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/8e8aab47672525536b0f5b3d094501ebea509164/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L405) you can see that the type of the messages used is the PubSub message JSON, not your content in JSON.

So, to prevent any issues (to query and to insert), write in another table and it should work nicely!

Comment: The line you pointed out did point me in the correct direction but I dont understand the second part of your answer. The comments in the code mention this
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/8e8aab47672525536b0f5b3d094501ebea509164/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L352-L354 
So would it be possible to create a UDF that converts csv to json and then the rest of the template could work as it was working before?

Comment: Yes, you can define a Javascript function in the options parameters which take a string in parameter and return a string. Your payload, the PubSub message, not only the CSV, but the whole PubSub JSON message is submitted to the JS function.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share your existing python code where you are parsing JSON format data and new & old data sample, So that it can be customized accordingly.

Moreover you can refer [Python code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/streaming_wordcount.py) here, it has performed word count transformation logic over PCollection, hopefully it can give you some refence to customize your code accrdingly.

Comment: I have added old and new data sample. I dont have the python code now because I was using the Java code provided by google as I have linked above. The problem is that this code only supports Json format as input but I need to shift over to csv. I will only shift over to python as a last resort because writing the entire code from scratch would be very time consuming.